# The cyclic sequence of even digits, with odds in between

Tags: code-golf, math, number, sequence

Consider the following sequence:

```
1, 0, 1, 2, 4, 1, 6, 8, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0, 1, ...
```

The even digits start from **0** and are grouped into runs of increasing length. They are arranged cyclically, meaning that they are sorted in ascending order until **8** is reached, and then cycled back from **0**. **1** separates the runs of even digits, and it also starts the sequence. Let's visualize how this sequence is formed:

```
                 1, 0, 1, 2, 4, 1, 6, 8, 0, 1, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1, 0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 1,  ...

                    -     ----     -------     ----------     -------------
run length:         1      2          3            4                5            ...
position of 1:   X     X        X           X              X                 X   ...
even sequence:      0,    2, 4,    6, 8, 0,    2, 4, 6, 8,    0, 2, 4, 6, 8      ...
```

---

Acceptable Input and Output methods:

- Receive an integer **N** as input and output the **N**th term of this sequence.
- Receive an integer **N** as input and output the first **N** terms of this sequence.
- Print the sequence indefinitely.

You can choose either 0 or 1-indexing for the first two methods.

You can compete in any [programming language](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2028/what-are-programming-languages/2073#2073), while using the [standard input and output methods](http://meta.codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2422/36398). [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are forbidden. This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest code in each language wins.

Comment: This challenge has been [sandboxed](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14191/59487).

Answer (score 8):

## [Haskell](https://www.haskell.org/), <s>50</s> 46 bytes

```hs
1#cycle[0,2..8]
n#r=1:take n r++(n+1)#drop n r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyflfbBvz31A5uTI5JzXaQMdIT88ilitPucjW0KokMTtVIU@hSFtbI0/bUFM5pSi/AMT/n5uYmadgq1BQlJlXoqCiAFZnaGCgUPz/X3JaTmJ68X/d5IICAA)

`1#cycle[0,2..8]` returns the sequence as infinite list.

*-4 bytes thanks to Ørjan Johansen!*

Comment: You can save four bytes by making the first argument of `#` just a number. [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0gszk7NyflfbBvz31A5uTI5JzXaQMdIT88ilitPucjW0KokMTtVIU@hSFtbI0/bUFM5pSi/AMT/n5uYmadgq1BQlJlXoqCiAFZnaGCgUPz/X3JaTmJ68X/d5IICAA "Haskell – Try It Online")

Answer (score 7):

### [Husk](https://github.com/barbuz/Husk), <s>12</s> <s>11</s> 10 bytes

```
ṁ:1CN¢mDŀ5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7//@HORitDZ79Di3JdjjaY/v8PAA)

Prints the sequence indefinitely.

Alternatively:

```
J1CΘN¢mDŀ5
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yygtzv7/38vQ@dwMv0OLcl2ONpj@/w8A)

#### Explanation

```
        ŀ5   Start from [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
      mD     Double each value to get [0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
     ¢       Repeat this list indefinitely, [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0, 2, ...]
   CN        Cut it into chunks of increasing lengths, 
             [[0], [2, 4], [6, 8, 0], ...]
ṁ:1          Prepend 1 to each sublist and concate the resulting lists.
```

For the alternative solution:

```
     ¢mDŀ5   Again, get [0, 2, 4, 6, 8, 0, 2, ...].
  CΘN        This time we prepend a zero to the natural numbers, which
             prepends an empty list to the resulting chunks.
J1           Join all the sublists with 1.
```

We could also do `...ΘCN...`, because `Θ` does "prepend default element", which prepends a zero for lists of integers and an empty list for lists of lists.

Answer (score 7):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 10 bytes

```
5ḶḤṁR€1pFḣ
```

Returns the first **n** items of the sequence.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8/9/04Y5tD3csebizMehR0xrDAreHOxb/BwobAAA)

#### How it works

```
5ḶḤṁR€1pFḣ  Main libk. Argument: n

5           Set the return value to 5.
 Ḷ          Unlength; yield [0, 1, 2, 3, 4].
  Ḥ         Unhalve; yield [0, 2, 4, 6, 8].
    R€      Range each; yield [[1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 3], ..., [1, ..., n]].
   ṁ        Mold; in the result to the left, replace [1] with [0], [1, 2] with
            [2, 4], [1, 2, 3] with [6, 8, 0], and so forth.
      1p    Take the Cartesian product of [1] and the result.
        F   Flatten the result.
         ḣ  Head; take the first n items of the result.
```

Comment: ಠ_ಠ `Unhalve`... Isn't that just `Double`?

Comment: It's just a mnemonic. `H` is *halve*, so `Ḥ` is *unhalve*. `ÆA` is *arccosine*, so `ÆẠ` is *unarccosine*.

Answer (score 4):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/), 52 bytes

```python
def f(n):t=(8*n+1)**.5+1;return 0==t%1or(n-t//2)%5*2
```

Takes a 1-based index and returns *True* or an integral *float*.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##HcxBDoIwEAXQNZzibxpmCojFNDGYehcTQdkMZJguPH01Jm/99o@9N7mU8pwXLCQ8WaKrlzaw96fYhpvOllVwTslc2JSkt2EY2UU/lmVTCFaBPuQ1U@gQA091pUj/rK52XcWocWNGf4fLIHdwAweSDvrDXL4)

Answer (score 2):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), <s>52</s> <s>59</s> 56 bytes

```apl
r←c k
r←~n←0
:For j :In ⍳k
n+←j-1
r,←1,⍨j⍴n⌽0,2×⍳4
:End
r←k⍴r
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT///qKO96FHbhGSF7P8gui4PSBhwWbnlFylkKVh55ik86t2czZWnDRTO0jXkKtIBMgx1HvWuyHrUuyXvUc9eAx2jw9OBiky4rFzzUrhAhmQDpYpAJv9PVjA2BQA)

This is a tradfn (**trad**itional **f**unctio**n**) taking one argument `k` and returning the first `k` items of the sequence.

Thanks to @GalenIvanov for pointing out an error in the function.
Thanks to @Adám for 3 bytes.

#### How it works:

```apl
r←c k             ⍝ The function c takes the argument k and results in r
r n←1 0           ⍝ Initializing the variables r and n, and setting them to 1 and 0, respectively.
:For j :In ⍳k     ⍝ For loop. ⍳k yields [1, 2, 3, ..., k], and j is the control variable.
n+←j-1            ⍝ Accumulates j-1 into n, so it follows the progression (0, 1, 3, 6, 10, 15...)
r,←1,⍨j⍴n⌽0,2×⍳4  ⍝ This line is explained below.
:End              ⍝ Ends the loop
r←k⍴r             ⍝ return the first k items of r.
                  ⍝ ⍴ actually reshapes the vector r to the shape of k;
                  ⍝ since k is a scalar, ⍴ reshapes r to a vector with k items.
            2×⍳4  ⍝ APL is 1-indexed by default, so this yields the vector 2 4 6 8
          0,      ⍝ Prepend a 0 to it. We now have 0 2 4 6 8
        n⌽        ⍝ Rotate the vector n times to the left.
      j⍴          ⍝ Reshape it to have j items, which cycles the vector.
   1,⍨            ⍝ Append a 1, then
r,←               ⍝ Append everything to r.
```

Below are a `Dfn`(**d**irect **f**unctio**n**) and a tacit function that also solve the challenge, both kindly provided by @Adám.

- Dfn: `{⍵⍴1,∊1,⍨¨j⍴¨(+\¯1+j←⍳⍵)⌽¨⊂0,2×⍳4}`  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBNWPerc@6t1iqPOoowtI9K44tCILyD@0QkM75tB6Q@2sR20THvVuBqrSfNSz99CKR11NBjpGh6cDxUxqjU0B)
- Tacit: `⊢⍴1,∘∊1,⍨¨⍳⍴¨(⊂0,2×⍳4)⌽⍨¨(+\¯1+⍳)`  [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT/8PBBqPuhY96t1iqPOoY8ajji4g3bvi0IpHvZuBgodWAGWbDHSMDk8HCphoPurZC5bV0I45tN5QGyimqWlsCgA)

Comment: I'm interested in the explanation of the tacit vesrion. Thanks!

Comment: @GalenIvanov I'll add one later today.

Comment: I noticed that the 3 functions yield incorrect answers - the subsequences always start from 0 after 1 - they should continue from the last even digit of the previous subsequence.

Comment: @GalenIvanov You're right. I'll see if I can fix it and add the explanations today.

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 51 bytes

```python
k=n=0
while 1:print 1;k+=1;exec'print n%10;n+=2;'*k
```

Prints the whole sequence.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/r/P9s2z9aAqzwjMydVwdCqoCgzr0TB0Dpb29bQOrUiNVkdIpKnamhgnadta2StrpX9/z8A)

Answer (score 2):

## APL, 25 bytes

Returns nth term.

```
1,(⌽n↑⌽(+/⍳n←⎕)⍴0,2×⍳4),1
```

Explanation

```
n←⎕     Prompts for screen input of integer
+/⍳      Creates a vector of integers of 1 to n and sums
⍴0,2×⍳4  Creates a vector by replicating 0 2 4 6 8 to the length of sum
⌽n↑⌽   Rotates the vector, selects first n elements and rotates result
        (selects last n elements}    
1,...,1 Concatenates 1s in front and behind result
```

Answer (score 1):

## JavaScript (ES6), <s>62</s> <s>54</s> 52 bytes

Returns the **N**th term of the sequence, 0-indexed.

```js
n=>(g=e=>n--?g(e+=k++<l?2:k=!++l):k<l?e%10:1)(k=l=0)
```

#### Demo

```js
let f =

n=>(g=e=>n--?g(e+=k++<l?2:k=!++l):k<l?e%10:1)(k=l=0)

for(n = 0; n < 30; n++) {
  console.log('a(' + n + ') = ' + f(n))
}
```

Answer (score 1):

## C (gcc), 84 bytes

```
i;j;f(){for(i=1;;i++){printf("%d ",1);for(j=0;j<i;)printf("%d ",(2*j+++i*i-i)%10);}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Vc0xCsMwDIXhuTmFCAQkK4G4q5rDGBWnMjQtpnQxPrvrjN3ezzc8XXbV1kySRKQSXxlt8yLGTOWd7fhEHKc7jLMnOTVtq6SbCf0hXl1iZnO2GE1@Jam1dYdnsAPPEfKuM@gjZHCux5egDJf@KUNtPw)

A function (`f()`) that prints the sequence infinitely, separated by spaces.

`i` is the length of the current even-run.

`j` is the index in the current even-run

`(2*j+++i*i-i)%10` gives the correct even number, given i and j (and increments j), equivalent to ((j+Tr(i))%5)*2, where Tr(x) is the xth triangular number (which is the number of even numbers that have been printed before the current even run;

Comment: [77 bytes](https://tio.run/##NYnNCoMwDIDP8ymygpA0CuuumQ9TItUUplLGLuKzd3rY7fvRflKtNUtCoz2tBW0IIsZMl@ThvhVbPgldAEeSXyb0L@0IrsOnz8xs3nqjNjxIjnpueEdb8IJYJu1A51jA@1O@BHtzS0jSHPUH "C (gcc) – Try It Online")

Answer (score 1):

## Java 8, 96 bytes

```java
v->{for(int i=0,j=-2,k;;i++,System.out.println(1))for(k=0;k++<i;System.out.println(j%=10))j+=2;}
```

Prints indefinitely, each number on a new line.

**Explanation:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/##bY7BCoMwEETv/Yq9FBKiol7T9A/qReil9JBGLYkxiomBIn67jdVjYZdllhnmKe553A@1UVW7Cs2thRuXZj4BSOPqseGihmKTAL6XFQh0347HNPyWsGGs404KKMAAg9XH17npRxTyIFkaKRbnUUupJCQqP9bVXdJPLhnGYNAGZRhv7paltCXkIukfjzqzLMVYEZbTZaV76zC9dGg9yn9wXUBHpQup9@MJHO/cJhHITFofyMv6BQ)

```java
v->{                               // Method with empty unused parameter and no return-type
  for(int i=0,                     //  Index integer, starting at 1
          j=-2,                    //  Even index integer, starting at -2
          k;                       //  Inner index integer
      ;                            //  Loop (1) indefinitely
                                   //    After every iteration:
       i++,                        //     Increase index `i` by 1
       System.out.println(1))      //     And print a 1
    for(k=0;                       //   Reset index `k` to 0
        k++<i;                     //   Inner loop (2) from 0 to `i`
                                   //     After every iteration:
       System.out.println(j%=10))  //      Set `j` to `j` modulo-10, and print it
      j+=2;                        //    Increase `j` by 2
                                   //   End of inner loop (2) (implicit / single-line body)
                                   //  End of loop (1) (implicit / single-line body)
}                                  // End of method
```

Answer (score 1):

### Batch, 85 bytes

```
@set/an=%2+1,t=n*-~n/2
@if %t% lss %1 %0 %1 %n%
@cmd/cset/a(%1-n)%%5*2*!!(t-=%1)+!t
```

Outputs the Nth term of the sequence. Works by calculating the next triangular number.

Answer (score 1):

## [J](http://jsoftware.com/), <strike>46</strike> <strike>42</strike> 40 bytes

-6 bytes thanks to cole

```
{.({.[:;[:#:&.>2^i.);@(1,&.><;.1)10|2*i.
```

Outputs the first N terms of this sequence.

How it works:

`10|[:+:i.` - generates a list of length N of 0 2 4 6 8 0 2 4... It simply takes  mod 10 of the doubled items of a list of integers starting at 0.

`[:;[:#:&.>2^i.` - generates a bit mask for cutting the above list.

(1 means start):  1 1 0 1 0 0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0 ... It finds 2 to the power of the consecutive non-negative integers, converts them into binary, flattens the list and takes only the first N items, so that the length of the both lists is the same.

`;@(1,&.><;.1)` - splits (cuts) the list of the even digits into sublistsaccording to the map of ones and zeroes, appends the sublist to 1 and finally flattens the resulting list

`]{.`  - takes only the first N items, getting rid of the additional numbers in the list due to the added 1s.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y/qfVqxgq6dgoGClYPC/Wk@jWi/ayjraStlKTc/OKC5TT9PaQcNQB8ixsdYz1DQ0qDHSytT7r8mlpKegnmZrpa6go1BrpZBWzJWanJGvkKZgZvD/PwA)

Comment: 42 bytes: `{.({.[:;[:#:&.>2^i.);@(1,&.><;.1)(10|2*i.)`. The changes I did were to use hooks and refactor the right tine of the fork to take advantage of how forks work. I like the `2^i.` trick.

I'm trying to work on the left tine of the fork now.

Comment: @cole Thanks, I need to learn to use forks better. Apparently the fork 2*i. is better then than the capped hook  [:+:i.

Comment: You can also drop the parens on the right tine `(10|2*i.)` ->`10|2*i.`

Answer (score 1):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 44 bytes

```perl
do{say 1;map{say(($r+=2)%10)}0..$i++}while 1
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/z8lv7o4sVLB0Do3sQDE0tBQKdK2NdJUNTTQrDXQ01PJ1NauLc/IzElVMPz//19@QUlmfl7xf11fUz0DQwMA)

Infinite output

Comment: -4 bytes `{...;redo}` instead of `do{...}while 1`

Answer (score 1):

## Common Lisp, 74 bytes

```
(do((b 1(1+ b))(k -2))(())(print 1)(dotimes(m b)(print(mod(incf k 2)10))))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##JYpbCoAwDASvks8NIpgeqa1C6BPb@8eAA8vAMqnqmmbIA4gkkIMiMwqdwQXffLVvEvZka7sXmhf/izYytKeHCgWWix2zDw)

Prints the sequence indefinitely.

Answer (score 1):

## Perl 5, 35 bytes

```
{say$i--?$r++%5*2:($i=++$j)>0;redo}
```

[try it online](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@6OLFSJVNX116lSFtb1VTLyEpDJdNWW1slS9POwLooNSW/9v//f/kFJZn5ecX/dX1N9QwMDQA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 17 bytes

```
9Ḷm2ẋ⁸ṁJR$$j1 1;ḣ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##ASgA1/9qZWxsef//OeG4tm0y4bqL4oG44bmBSlIkJGoxIDE74bij////MTAw)

Answer (score 0):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 55 bytes

```
i=0 j=-2while1{for k:0..i print(j=(j+2)%10)print(1)i++}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KyjKL8nP@/8/09ZAIctW16g8IzMn1bA6Lb9IIdvKQE8vU6GgKDOvRCPLViNL20hT1dBAEyJgqJmprV37/z8A)

Prints the sequence indefinitely

Comment: ಠ_ಠ What is that, new syntax? :p `i=0 j=-2while1{`...

Comment: @Mr.Xcoder :P `-2while` is just like Python and `while1` is because I made identifiers not able to be a keyword followed by a number

Answer (score 0):

## [Java (OpenJDK 8)](http://openjdk.java.net/), 107 bytes

```java
i->{String b="";for(int l=i,r=0,z=0;i>0;b+=l-i--==r?(l=i)<1+r++*0?"1":"1":"02468".charAt(z++%5));return b;}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VY9Ba4NAEIXv@RWDUNCsLhraUrpZQw8t9FB6yLH0sK4mHau7so4BE/ztdkm8dGAu781jvlerk0psV5m6/J2x7awjqL3GB8KGHwajCa3ha7HqhqJBDbpRfQ8fCg1cVj0p8trbcrZ9N1QdKxfDnhyaYw561D70eqrMZ1mChBmT/HIzoZBBIA7WhWgIGomxk2l8lqnAPBUFk02CSSKl24XejLYZc4yt012QBc/XTTf3j08B1z/KvVB4ZuzuIYqEq2hwBgoxzWJBXihPFktoPXh4A/j6BhX5ErDMfuyparkdiHfep/AfPFdd14xhtvE/rpFpmv8A)

Answer (score 0):

## Mathematica, 68 bytes

Returns the Nth term

```
Insert[Join@@Table[{0,2,4,6,8},#^2],1,Array[{(2-#+#^2)/2}&,#]][[#]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zgq/DfM684tagk2is/M8/BISQxKSc1utpAx0jHRMdMx6JWRznOKFbHUMexqCixMrpaw0hXWRsopKlvVKumoxwbGx0NJNT@BxRl5pU4pEUbGhgYxP4HAA)

Answer (score 0):

### [Wolfram Language (Mathematica)](https://www.wolfram.com/wolframscript/), 61 bytes

```
Flatten[TakeList[2Mod[r=0~Range~#,5],UpTo/@r]~Riffle~1][[#]]&
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syUjNTSzJTE78n6Zgq/DfLSexpCQ1LzokMTvVJ7O4JNrINz8lusjWoC4oMS89tU5ZxzRWJ7QgJF/foSi2LigzLS0ntc4wNjpaOTZWDWhEnYJjUVFiJZA2NDBQ0NdXCCjKzCv5DwA)

Answer (score 0):

## JavaScript, 45 bytes

1 indexed:

```
f=(x,t=0,p=0)=>p<x?f(x-1,t+1,p+t):x-p?x%5*2:1
```

0 indexed:

```
g=(x,p=0)=>p<x?g(x-1,p?++t+p:t=1):x-p?x%5*2:1
```

```js
    f=(x,t=0,p=0)=>p<x?f(x-1,t+1,p+t):x-p?x%5*2:1

g=(x,p=0)=>p<x?g(x-1,p?++t+p:t=1):x-p?x%5*2:1


a.value=[...Array(100)].map((_,i)=>f(i+1))
b.value=[...Array(100)].map((_,i)=>g(i))
```

```html
<output id=a></output>
<output id=b></output>
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Ruby](https://www.ruby-lang.org/), <s>48</s> 46 bytes

```ruby
a=b=c=0;loop{a>b&&(p 2*b%10;b+=1)||a+=c+=p(1)}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##KypNqvz/P9E2yTbZ1sA6Jz@/oDrRLklNTaNAwUgrSdXQwDpJ29ZQs6YmUds2Wdu2QMNQs/b/fwA)

Print the sequence indefinitely

Answer (score 0):

## bash, 42 bytes

```
for((;;)){ echo $[i--?r++%5*2:(i=++j)>0];}
```

or 34 if valid

```
echo $[i--?r++%5*2:(i=++j)>0];. $0
```

[try it online](https://tio.run/##S0oszvj/Py2/SEPD2lpTs1ohNTkjX0ElOlNX175IW1vVVMvISiPTVls7S9POINa69v9/AA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Pip](https://github.com/dloscutoff/pip), 15 bytes

```
W P1L UiP2*Uv%t
```

Prints indefinitely. [Try it here!](https://replit.com/@dloscutoff/pip) Or, here's a 16-byte equivalent in Pip Classic: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8gs@P8/XCHA0EdbOzPASEtbu0y15P///7o5AA)

#### Explanation

```
W                While this expression is truthy--
  P1             print 1 (evaluates to 1, which is truthy)
                 --loop:
      Ui          Increment i (initially 0)
    L             and loop that many times:
           Uv      Increment v (initially -1)
         2*        Multiply by 2
             %t    Mod 10
        P          Print
```